# Use Snappy Core without Ubuntu One account

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-core, single-sign-on

## Background

There has been a recent interest within the company for whom I work to improve security and remove all unnecessary parts of operating systems. This is a perfect use-case for the Ubuntu Snappy Core system. From what I can tell, however, using a Snappy Core machine requires that Ubuntu's SSO, Ubuntu One, be used to set up the computer. The SSO isn't something that my company would agree to use and would therefore limit my ability to use this OS.

## Question

Is it possible use a snappy core machine without using an Ubuntu One sign-on? If so, how can I do so?